# Check if null value is retrieved from an external service

Tags: android, json, web-services

I´m retrieving values from an external database into an android application doing a call on a service that's on the server. Here's the php file:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (!$mysqli) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . sqli_connect_error());
}

$q=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT title FROM post WHERE UPPER(title) LIKE UPPER('%" . $_REQUEST['searchThis'] . "%')");

while($e=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $output[]=$e;
}

print(json_encode($output)); 
mysqli_close();
```

And this is what my class does (I wrote only the code that matters):

```
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("CONNECTION_ERROR", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}

try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();

        ///-------------SYSTEM OUTS---------------

    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(result.getClass().getName());
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("BUFFER_ERROR", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

//------------------PROBLEMS---------------
if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
    list.add("empty");
}

else{
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //Log.i("result",json_data.getString("title"));
            String title = json_data.getString("title");
            list.add(title);
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("DATA_PARSING_ERROR", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
}
return list;
```

}

I've tried whit logs and prints and what I'm getting is:

```
null //FOR System.out.println(result);
java.lang.String //for System.out.println(result.getClass().getName());
```

It works when the php service on the server returns something, the problem is that when I compare result with "null" it's always false even though result is a string with value "null". Then of course I run into a JSON exception because result isn't a valid format for conversion. What could be possibly wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not seem to consider the trailing newline character ('\n') appended by you.

You can either remove the appending of the newline character ('\n') in the while loop or remove it when you check for "null".